# What is the difference between BuildConfig.groovy and Config.groovy?

Tags: grails

I have a grails app. Why do some properties work in one but not the other? When do I put properties in one and when do I put them in the other one?

Comment: You could get your answer [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#config).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Grails doc [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#config)

> The first,
>   BuildConfig.groovy, is for settings that are used when running Grails
>   commands, such as compile, doc, etc. The second file, Config.groovy,
>   is for settings that are used when your application is running. This
>   means that Config.groovy is packaged with your application, but
>   BuildConfig.groovy is not.

Comment: well BuildConfig.groovy is packaged under another name: dependencies.groovy