# Grails: why is the Config.groovy file executed during compilation?

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, configuration, log4j

From [the Grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.7/guide/conf.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600252/what-is-the-difference-between-buildconfig-groovy-and-config-groovy) question:

> For general configuration Grails provides two files:
>
> 1. grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
> 2. grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
>
> Both of them use Groovy's ConfigSlurper syntax. The first, BuildConfig.groovy, is for settings that are used when running Grails commands, such as compile, doc, etc. The second file, Config.groovy, is for settings that are used when your application is running. This means that Config.groovy is packaged with your application, but BuildConfig.groovy is not.

And here is an extract about the `log4j` framework:

> Grails uses its common configuration mechanism to provide the settings for the underlying Log4j log system, so all you have to do is add a log4j setting to the file grails-app/conf/**Config.groovy**.

I have a project with these two files: `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` and `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`. The project uses the `log4j` utility, so some settings (including a function) are placed in the **Config.groovy** file. Now, according to the documentation I quoted, it is the right file, since I want to use the logging utilities for running the application, not compiling it.

What's interesting, these settings are used when I run `mvn package` on my project - the function inside the `log4j` settings is executed.

According to both [the documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.7/guide/conf.html) and [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600252/what-is-the-difference-between-buildconfig-groovy-and-config-groovy) this should not be the case.

I know that it is possible to use the `grailsApplication` to access these settings:

```
def recipient = grailsApplication.config.foo.bar.hello
```

So I searched my project and found some usages of the `grailsApplication`, but none related to the log4j settings.

What are other possible reasons of having the log4j settings that are placed in the **Config.groovy** file used during `mvn package`? What am I missing?

**Update:** the mentioned configuration seems to work when I use `mvn package` to build my project for the first time. Next time I run `mvn package`, the `log4j` configuration from the `Config.groovy` file is used. And if I delete the job workspace, it works well again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one important thing worth mentioning. Even though `Config.groovy` is used by application at the runtime, it has to be compiled to Java's `Config.class` in the first place. When you package your application compiler has to access this file and compile it to the bytecode. Take a look at the listing I've pasted below, it comes from one Grails application I have in my workspace:

#### Command:

```
ls -l target/classes | awk '{print $8}'
```

#### Ouptput:

```
application.properties
BootStrap.class
BootStrap$_closure1.class
BootStrap$_closure2.class
BuildConfig.class
BuildConfig$_run_closure1.class
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure2.class
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure3.class
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure4.class
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure5.class
com
Config.class
Config$_run_closure1.class
Config$_run_closure1_closure4.class
Config$_run_closure1_closure4_closure5.class
Config$_run_closure1_closure4_closure5_closure6.class
Config$_run_closure2.class
Config$_run_closure2_closure7.class
Config$_run_closure2_closure8.class
Config$_run_closure3.class
DataSource.class
DataSource$_run_closure1.class
DataSource$_run_closure2.class
DataSource$_run_closure3.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure4.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure4_closure7.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure5.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure5_closure8.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure6.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure6_closure9.class
DataSource$_run_closure3_closure6_closure9_closure10.class
resources.class
resources$_run_closure1.class
UrlMappings.class
UrlMappings$__clinit__closure1.class
UrlMappings$__clinit__closure1_closure2.class
UrlMappings$__clinit__closure1_closure2_closure3.class
```

You can see that `Config.groovy` file was compiled to `Config.class` file and all closures that were used inside `Config.groovy` were compiled to Java's anonymous classes (e.g. `Config$_run_closure1_closure4.class`). That's why if you put some code that executes any logic to `Config.groovy` you have to expect it will be compiled and executed since compiled class extends `groovy.lang.Script` and it executes body of a Groovy script file. Below you can find what does `Groovy.class` file looks like:

#### Command:

```
javap -l  target/classes/Config.class
```

#### Output:

```
Compiled from "Config.groovy"
public class Config extends groovy.lang.Script {
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;

  public static long __timeStamp;

  public static long __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1501076781354;

  public Config();
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          4       4     0  this   LConfig;

  public Config(groovy.lang.Binding);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          4      21     0  this   LConfig;
          4      21     1 context   Lgroovy/lang/Binding;

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      19     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;

  public java.lang.Object run();
    LineNumberTable:
      line 14: 4
      line 17: 43
      line 18: 126
      line 24: 194
      line 26: 233
      line 30: 296
      line 31: 323
      line 38: 376
      line 42: 419
      line 45: 453
      line 63: 473
      line 65: 507
      line 68: 550
      line 70: 595
      line 72: 631
      line 74: 679
      line 77: 724
      line 80: 777
      line 84: 822
      line 86: 867
      line 88: 912
      line 99: 932
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0     964     0  this   LConfig;

  public java.lang.Object this$dist$invoke$3(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      68     0  this   LConfig;
          0      68     1  name   Ljava/lang/String;
          0      68     2  args   Ljava/lang/Object;

  public void this$dist$set$3(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      53     0  this   LConfig;
          0      53     1  name   Ljava/lang/String;
          0      53     2 value   Ljava/lang/Object;

  public java.lang.Object this$dist$get$3(java.lang.String);
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      46     0  this   LConfig;
          0      46     1  name   Ljava/lang/String;

  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();

  public static void __$swapInit();

  static {};

  public int super$1$hashCode();

  public void super$3$printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);

  public void super$3$printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);

  public void super$3$setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);

  public boolean super$1$equals(java.lang.Object);

  public void super$1$finalize();

  public groovy.lang.Binding super$3$getBinding();

  public void super$3$print(java.lang.Object);

  public void super$3$setBinding(groovy.lang.Binding);

  public java.lang.Object super$3$evaluate(java.io.File);

  public java.lang.String super$1$toString();

  public java.lang.Object super$3$evaluate(java.lang.String);

  public void super$2$setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass);

  public void super$1$notify();

  public java.lang.Object super$3$invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);

  public java.lang.Object super$1$clone();

  public void super$1$wait(long, int);

  public void super$1$wait(long);

  public void super$1$wait();

  public groovy.lang.MetaClass super$2$getMetaClass();

  public java.lang.Class super$1$getClass();

  public void super$3$run(java.io.File, java.lang.String[]);

  public void super$3$println(java.lang.Object);

  public void super$1$notifyAll();

  public java.lang.Object super$3$getProperty(java.lang.String);

  public void super$3$println();

  static java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
}
```

#### Update

Now to understand why `Config.groovy` is executed we need to dig into what happens when `grails package` is being executed. Running `grails package` command makes `_GrailsPackage.groovy` script from grails-core being executed. `packageApp` target calls `GrailsProjectPackager.packageApplication()`

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-scripts/src/main/scripts/_GrailsPackage.groovy#L48

This method calls `createConfig()` helper class:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-project-api/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/project/packaging/GrailsProjectPackager.groovy#L274

In `createConfig()` method implementation we can find `ConfigSlurper.parse(script)` execution:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-project-api/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/project/packaging/GrailsProjectPackager.groovy#L345

This is a Groovy class that parses a script and in the end it calls `script.run()` on the script that was parsed. It's easy to find out with a debugger - check my video where I show how to do it in this particular example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2PN6TjFjUI

I hope it helps.

Comment: Are you saing that I should expect the `Config.groovy` class to be compiled AND executed at compile time, because it extends `groovy.lang.Script`? Why? It contradicts the documentation I quoted. So even if I don't run any tests using `mvn test`, will this class be executed?

Comment: @user2738748 Not exactly. It does not happen while compiling the app, but while the app is being packaged. You can simply run `grails compile` and `Config.class` wont be executed. It's being executed when `grails package` is called. Take a look at this log - https://gist.github.com/wololock/9d0cf2f4039bf0554597fa86728fcea1 I've added `println "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"` in the end of `Config.groovy` file. As you can see it has been executed twice during packaging process.

Comment: I see, but I still don't understand, why this class is executed when the app is being packaged. Packaging the app has nothing to do with running it.

Comment: @user2738748 It happens in this line of `GrailsProjectPackager` class - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-project-api/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/project/packaging/GrailsProjectPackager.groovy#L345 I've recorded a screen cast where I run `grails package` with debugger to show each step and what happens when `ConfigSlurper.parse(script)` is called. I will also update my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`mvn package` will run other maven phases and that includes the `test` phase. Grails integration tests will bootstrap your full app so the Config.groovy file will be parsed.